# Oracle Mobile MAF Date Time picker

Tags: date, mobile, time, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I am using the regular input date-picker. But after selecting a date, there is no convenient way to confirm the selection. Something like  a DONE  button that will elegant than clicking anywhere outside to "select". Like the 'clear" button, which is there on the frame. Any suggestions where to get a good date-time picker?

[image]

I understand there is no easy Calendar-Date pickup available in MAF unless one installs the Cordova-PhoneGap-Calendar for iOS!

BTW, I found a good date-Picker in Oracle-Wiki (Link Below). In fact, I want something imilar,but  either the given code is not the right one or I am missing something.
I have no idea, how to use the Oracle WiKi. Any help on a good Date-Time picker is appreciated.

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/ADFMobileDesign/Component+-+Input+Date

Comment: Did you look at the sample code for inputDate in CompGallery at Middelware\jdeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.maf\Samples\PublicSamples ?

Comment: Yes, but which sample has this?

Comment: InputDate usage at: PublicSamples\CompGallery\ViewController\public_html\inputDate.amx